# how to use ng container in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to view list  asks in survey  but I don't know how to use ng-container in ionic

ForLoop.html

SORULAR

```
               <ion-label>{{currentDongu}}</ion-label>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let dongu  of donguler" [value]="dongu.value">
                  {{dongu.value}}
                  {{dongu.label}}
                  {{dongu.secenek1}}
                  {{dongu.secenek2}}
                  {{dongu.secenek3}}

              </ng-container>

      </ion-item>
```

ForLoop.ts

export class ForloopPage {

```
key:0;
Showbutton=true;
```

constructor(
      private storage: Storage
    ) {

```
}

get currentDongu(){
  return this.donguler[this.key]
}
```

ileri(){

this.key++;

```
  if(this.key==13) {
    this.Showbutton=false;
  }
```

}

Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.
1. If 'value' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("tion>{{currentDongu}}

```
              <ng-container *ngFor="let dongu  of donguler" [ERROR ->][value]="dongu.value">

                  {{dongu.value}}
```

"): ng:///AppModule/ForloopPage.html@60:64

Answer (score 0):

Actually , The error itself says a lot about the problem . Value property is not available on grouping elements such as ng-container.

Also you don't need to bind [value]="someValue".
If you write `<ng-container *ngFor="let item of someArray">{{ item }}</ng-container>` , it will repeat this ng-container for each item in someArray in your ts file e.g.

```
someArray = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}].
```

Now using *ngFor on someArray like -

`<ng-container *ngFor="let item of someArray">{{ item.id }}</ng-container>`

will manipulate *ngFor like this-

`<ng-container>1</ng-container>`

`<ng-container>2</ng-container>`

`<ng-container>3</ng-container>`

Also, since ng-container is a grouping element, it doesn't actually appear in DOM , so the content will go directly in parent component like-

```
<some-parent-component>
1
2
3
</some-parent-component>
```

Just a suggestion, you can use `<ion-list>` to group individual `<ion-item>` inside it and you can apply *ngFor on `ion-item` itself.

Check out the documentation here - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/list